# List for Office backstage in Ribbon XML

Tags: ms-word, vsto, ribbon, ribbonx

Is there any Ribbon XML for a list of files like control similar to Word's File -> Open -> Recent listing on the Backstage? The Intellisense for the XML doesn't provide any hints.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not in the [list of control IDs](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50745) (this one is for 2016) it probably can't be moved or re-used. There are many controls like this, it's not entirely exposed to third party developers.